# How to Disable Connected Disconnected spam message on TeamSpeak3

Tags: teamspeak

Im playing League of Legends with teamspeak3 with some friends and there's a really anoying message spam on the top of the screen (which covers a 5mm line of all the top), for each ts user that Connects to the server, and stays about 5 secs there covering my sight.

That's for just 1 user. When 8 or 10 users connect at the same time this makes impossible to keep playing because those annoying messages stack, transforming not to just annoying but a death pact.

Is there a way to sweep those out.. like forever?
Thanks in advance MMO players!

Answer (score 1):

Although league of legends isn't an MMO ;) . I figure you can just disable the options in teamspeak to show those messages, just like skype, msn ...

Try the settings -> messages tab